# Request.body is undefined in second post request

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express

I searched for similar symptoms, but couldn't find my case.

I have body-parser installed and

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

this written.

But if I have multiple POST requests, only first req.body is recognized and secondary req.body only returns {}.

PLEASE HELP

Comment: What do you mean by "secondary req.body"? Can you include the code that makes the POST request?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I only declared id for HTML  tag.

I added name for the tag and it worked perfectly!

I would be appreciated if someone explained difference between id and name for HTML tag...